# A basic question on lebesgue integration

Tags: measure-theory

I want to prove that the function $2x\sin(\frac{1}{x^2}) - \frac{2}{x}\cos(\frac{1}{x^2})$ is not integrable in [-1,1]. I know how to prove $\frac{1}{x}$ is not integrable (lebesgue) in $[0,1]$. How to proceed ?

Comment: Depending on your definition of *integrable*, show that either both or one of $f^+$ and $f^-$ are not finite.

Comment: Also note that $2x \sin (1/x)$ is bounded, so you can focus on showing $\frac 2x \cos (1/x^2)$ not integrable.